# How to specify Django backend?

Tags: python, django

I do not understand what is wrong with my Django backend specification

```
These are my urls

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from django.conf.urls import url
from store import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('store.urls')),
    url(r'^accounts', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

This is the tree structure

```
bookstore
├── bookstore
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   └── wsgi.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── requirements.txt
└── store
    ├── admin.py
    ├── apps.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── migrations
    │   ├── 0001_initial.py
    │   ├── 0002_auto_20180604_0751.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── __pycache__
    │       ├── 0001_initial.cpython-36.pyc
    │       ├── 0002_auto_20180604_0751.cpython-36.pyc
    │       └── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
    ├── models.py
    ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── admin.cpython-36.pyc
    │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
    │   ├── models.cpython-36.pyc
    │   ├── urls.cpython-36.pyc
    │   └── views.cpython-36.pyc
    ├── templates
    │   ├── registration
    │   │   ├── activate.html
    │   │   ├── activation_complete.html
    │   │   ├── activation_email_subject.txt
    │   │   ├── activation_mail.txt
    │   │   ├── registration_complete.html
    │   │   └── registration_form.html
    │   ├── store.html
    │   └── template.html
    ├── tests.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── views.py
```

Now when I try 
python manage.py runserver
I got this
[image]

Also in terminal shows me

```
Not Found: /accounts
[05/Jun/2018 09:08:17] "GET /accounts HTTP/1.1" 404 5632
```

If I go for

```
url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
```

then I have

```
1. ^accounts/
```

....

The current path, accounts, didn't match any of these.

How to fix this?
How does Django backend work?
I am using 2.0.5 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `path` instead of `url`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('store.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

By the way, if Django version <= 1.11, use `url`. (`path` was added after 2.0)

Comment: No,2.0.5 verison.But still it does not work.I got The current path, accounts, didn't match any of these.

Comment: @MikiBelavista You should visit `127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/` not just `/accounts/`

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
url(r'^/', include('store.urls')),
```

Rather than

```
url(r'^accounts', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
url(r'^', include('store.urls')),
```